# Alterar cor da fonte de uma coluna do DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estou tentando alterar a cor da fonte somente dar célula de uma coluna que contenha "x" valor... porém só estou conseguindo alterar da linha inteira... tentei fazer somente da célula porém sem sucesso, segue código usado até o momento.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tableLeitura.Rows)
{

    if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["GLicemiaCalc"].Value) > 180)
    {
         // Se celula for menor que 70
         row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente precisa desenvolver uma rotina que intera sobre cada `row` ([DataGridViewRow](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow?view=net-5.0)) contido no [DataGridView](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=net-5.0) e testar o valor de uma determinada célula e com o resultado depois testar o ***valor*** retornado se o mesmo satisfaz o valor ***180***, *exemplo*:

```
private void Color_DataGridView()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
                       //row.Cells["GLicemiaCalc"]
        if (int.TryParse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out int value))
        {
            if (value > 180)
            {
                row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui aqui.